# Can MSBuild binaries be used on their own?

Tags: deployment, msbuild, production-environment, nant

I've been using NAnt for sometime and although it works pretty well most of the time, some functionality is so limited you find yourself doing a page worth of work instead of couple of lines.

My biggest problem is returning results from exec task.. you HAVE to output to file then read the file then in my case substring what you read.
Multiply that by 8 different queries and you have lots of unnecessary work.

Anyway I would like to switch MSBuild which has much better support in this case.

But the problem is that I am using CI + Nant to deploy on staging and sometimes production and Nant is just a directory with files that you copy.

But As far as I know MSBuild must be installed and registered.

Is there such a thing as a standalone MSBuild download?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't have time today to write up a rough history for MSBuild (I already covered ASP.NET on IIS and C# compilers), but I would tell you that MSBuild is not only standalone today, but open source at GitHub,

https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild

You can download the installers from Microsoft Downloads, or you can compile your own.

Reference: [Rough History of MSBuild](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-msbuild-cc72a217fa98?source=linkShare-509776cef47e-1509582835)